# Не работает микрофон RAZER Blackshark v2

Tags: аудио

Добрый день/вечер комрады.
Купил вчера замечательную гарнитуру razer blackshark v2. Проблема следующая: установился спец микшер razer synapse, через него все работает.
Но в играх и панели управления звуком ничего не работает. Дрова менял ситуация та-же.
Хелп

Comment: Проблема решена:
Windows 10 
Пуск->Настройки->Конфиденциальность->Микрофон-> Слайдер в положение включено "Разрешить приложениям доступ к микрофону"